# Clicks / Distortion in AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

When I add a bunch (20-40) samples playing and overlapping eachother simultaneously sometimes it starts getting distorted and then some waving, oscillating, and clicking begins to happen.  A similar sound happens when the samples are playing the the app crashes - sounds like an abrupt, crunchy halt.

Notice the waviness begins between 0:05 and 0:10; nasty clicks start around 0:15.

[Listen Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajg1203u80tpe83/mindflower%20clicks.m4a?dl=0)

How can I make it smoother?  I am spawning AKPlayer objects (from 4.1) that play 4-8 second .wav files.  Those go into AKBoosters which go into AKMixers which go into the final AKMixer for output.

**Edit:**

Many PenAudioNodes get plugged into the mixer of the AudioReceiver singleton.

Here's my AudioReceiver singleton:

```
class AudioReceiver {
    static var sharedInstance = AudioReceiver()
    private var audioNodes = [UUID : AudioNode]()
    private let mixer = AKMixer()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "audio-queue")

    //MARK: - Setup & Teardown

    init() {
        AudioKit.output = mixer //peakLimiter
        AudioKit.start()
    }

    //MARK: - Public

    func audioNodeBegan(_ message : AudioNodeMessage) {
        queue.async {
            var audioNode: AudioNode?
            switch message.senderType {
            case .pen:
                audioNode = PenAudioNode()
            case .home:
                audioNode = LoopingAudioNode(with: AudioHelper.homeLoopFile())
            default:
                break
            }
            if let audioNode = audioNode {
                self.audioNodes[message.senderId] = audioNode
                self.mixer.connect(input: audioNode.output)
                audioNode.start(message)
            }
        }
    }

    func audioNodeMoved(_ message : AudioNodeMessage) {
        queue.async {
            if let audioNode = self.audioNodes[message.senderId] {
                audioNode.update(message)
            }
        }
    }

    func audioNodeEnded(_ message : AudioNodeMessage) {
        queue.async {
            if let audioNode = self.audioNodes[message.senderId] {
                audioNode.stop(message)
            }
            self.audioNodes[message.senderId] = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my PenAudioNode:

```
class PenAudioNode {
    fileprivate var mixer: AKMixer?
    fileprivate var playersBoosters = [AKPlayer : AKBooster]()
    fileprivate var finalOutput: AKNode?
    fileprivate let file: AKAudioFile = AudioHelper.randomBellSampleFile()

    //MARK: - Setup & Teardown

    init() {
        mixer = AKMixer()
        finalOutput = mixer!
    }
}

extension PenAudioNode: AudioNode {
    var output: AKNode {
        return finalOutput!
    }

    func start(_ message: AudioNodeMessage) {
    }

    func update(_ message: AudioNodeMessage) {
        if let velocity = message.velocity {
            let newVolume = Swift.min((velocity / 50) + 0.1, 1)
            mixer!.volume = newVolume
        }
        if let isClimactic = message.isClimactic, isClimactic {
            let player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
            player.completionHandler = { [weak self] in
                self?.playerCompleted(player)
            }
            let booster = AKBooster(player)
            playersBoosters[player] = booster
            booster.rampTime = 1
            booster.gain = 0
            mixer!.connect(input: booster)
            player.play()
            booster.gain = 1
        }
    }

    func stop(_ message: AudioNodeMessage) {
        for (_, booster) in playersBoosters {
            booster.gain = 0
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
            self.mixer!.stop()
            self.output.disconnectOutput()
        }
    }

    private func playerCompleted(_ player: AKPlayer) {
        playersBoosters.removeValue(forKey: player)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you could show a small snippet of code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Just added some code, dave234, to the question.

Comment: Could you reduce it to the smallest amount of code that can reproduce the issue.  There seems to be a bunch of application logic in there.

Comment: If its too hard to remove the application logic, you can share the whole project on github and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks Aurelius, I will share the project with you.

Comment: Have you got a solution to this problem?

Comment: @arsenium No I have not.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are not releasing objects and you are eventually overloading the audio engine with too many instances of processing nodes connected in the graph. In particular not releasing AKBoosters will cause an issue like this. I can't really tell what your code is doing, but if you are spawning objects without releasing them properly, it will lead to garbled audio.

You want to conserve objects as much as possible and make sure you are using the absolute minimum amount of AKNode based processing.

There are various ways to debug this, but you can start by printing out the current state of the AVAudioEngine:

```
AudioKit.engine.description
```

That will show how many nodes you have connected in the graph at any given moment.

Comment: Could you explian how can we "release" AKBoosters in audioKit? you mean calling a detach on the unused nodes?

Comment: Also not clear for me " make sure you are using the absolute minimum amount of AKNode based processing." I can create a new questiion if you like?

Comment: @Spring Yes, you use AudioKit.detach. Also disconnecting it from the signal chain. AudioKit.detach(nodes: [faderNode.avAudioUnitOrNode])
        faderNode = nil

Comment: @Spring meaning, you want to avoid having any memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks. But then there is no function as "attach" for later use ? And for the disconnect, should it be "disconnectInput" or "disconnectOutput"?

Comment: @Spring yes, that's how it is currently. Not the most intuitive for sure. You can do disconnectOutput on the node in question.